# Oracle Transpose multiple rows to columns such that for each group data is visible next to each other

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to transpose data for a table and i am not able to do that. I am using Oracle 12c. Test data looks like this.

```
+----+-----+-----+ 
| ID | VAL | sum | 
+----+-----+-----+ 
| a  |   3 |  15 | 
| b  |   5 |  90 | 
| c  |   8 |  36 | 
| c  |   9 |  45 |
+----+-----+-----+
```

and output should look like

```
+----+-----+-----+------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+ 
| ID | VAL | sum | ID_1 | VAL_1 | sum_1 | ID_2 | VAL_2 | sum_2 | 
+----+-----+-----+------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+ 
| a  |   3 |  15 | b    |     5 |    90 | c    |     8 |    36 |
|    |     |     |      |       |       | c    |     9 |    45 |
+----+-----+-----+------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+
```

I do not want hard coded data because the data in the table is huge and can have thousands of records.

Comment: Would there always be just 3 IDs?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - No there could be any number of ID's

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation -- after calculating the line number using `row_number()`:

```
select max(case when id = 'A' then val end) as val_a,
       max(case when id = 'A' then sum end) as sum_a,
       max(case when id = 'B' then val end) as val_b,
       max(case when id = 'B' then sum end) as sum_b,
       max(case when id = 'C' then val end) as val_c,
       max(case when id = 'C' then sum end) as sum_c       
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by val) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but there could be any number of ID's  and it is practically impossible to hard code their values

Comment: @nikhilsharma . . . If you don't know the columns in the result set, then you need to use dynamic SQL to generate the query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to build it automatically, you need dynamic SQL embedded in a procedure or function. In my example below, I use only an anonymous pl/sql block.

Here the details

```
SQL> create table t ( id varchar2(10) , val number, sum number );

Table created

SQL> insert into t values ( 'a' , 3, 15 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL>  insert into t values ( 'b' , 4, 22 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ( 'c' , 5, 90 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ( 'd' , 10, 33 );

1 row created.

SQL>  insert into t values ( 'e' , 22, 50 );

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

 SQL> select * from t ;

ID                VAL        SUM
---------- ---------- ----------
a                   3         15
b                   4         22
c                   5         90
d                  10         33
e                  22         50
```

I am going to follow an approach where the maximum number of total distinct values for ID is not greater than 1000, which is the database limit. Here you can find more information regarding limits:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited lines 220 pages 0
declare
v_query       clob;
out_string    varchar2(100);
cursor c_ids 
is 
select distinct id, count(id) over () tot_rows from t order by id asc;
procedure print_clob_to_output (p_clob in clob)
    is
      l_offset     pls_integer := 1;
      l_chars      pls_integer;
    begin
        --dbms_output.put_line('Print CLOB');
        loop
            exit when l_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);
            l_chars := dbms_lob.instr(p_clob, chr(10), l_offset, 1);
            if l_chars is null or l_chars = 0 then
                l_chars := dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob) + 1;
            end if;
            -- dbms_output.put_line('> ' || dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, l_chars - l_offset, l_offset));
            dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, l_chars - l_offset, l_offset));
            l_offset := l_chars + 1;
        end loop;
    end print_clob_to_output;
begin
    dbms_output.enable(null);
    for item in c_ids 
    loop
        if item.tot_rows >= 1000
        then 
            raise_application_error(-20001,'Maximum number of 1000 columns are not allowed',true);
        end if;
        out_string := item.id;
        if c_ids%rowcount = 1 
        then 
            v_query := 'select';
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,' max(case when id = '''||out_string||''' then val end) as val_'||out_string||' , ');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,' max(case when id = '''||out_string||''' then sum end) as sum_'||out_string||' ,'); 
        elsif c_ids%rowcount < item.tot_rows then
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,' max(case when id = '''||out_string||''' then val end) as val_'||out_string||' ,');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,' max(case when id = '''||out_string||''' then sum end) as sum_'||out_string||' ,'); 
        else 
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,' max(case when id = '''||out_string||''' then val end) as val_'||out_string||' ,');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,' max(case when id = '''||out_string||''' then sum end) as sum_'||out_string); 
        end if;
    end loop;
    dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
    dbms_lob.append(v_query,'from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by val) as seqnum from t ) t');
    dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
    dbms_lob.append(v_query,'group by seqnum');
    print_clob_to_output(v_query);
end;
/
```

With this piece of code I can create the query up to 1000 different IDs. Here I show you how it would work with a lot of more IDs. The process does not add the sql terminator to the query itself, just in case you want to run it by execute immediate. If not, to run the output of the clob, put '/' or ';' at the end of the query.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on size unlimited lines 220 pages 400 long 99999999
SQL> declare
v_query       clob;
out_string    varchar2(100);
  2    3    4  cursor c_ids
is
select distinct id, count(id) over () tot_rows from t order by id asc;
procedure print_clob_to_output (p_clob in clob)
  5    6    7    8      is
      l_offset     pls_integer := 1;
      l_chars      pls_integer;
    begin
        --dbms_output.put_line('Print CLOB');
        loop
  9   10   11   12   13   14              exit when l_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);
 15              l_chars := dbms_lob.instr(p_clob, chr(10), l_offset, 1);
            if l_chars is null or l_chars = 0 then
                l_chars := dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob) + 1;
            end if;
            -- dbms_output.put_line('> ' || dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, l_chars - l_offset, l_offset));
 16   17   18   19   20                         dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, l_chars - l_offset, l_offset));
            l_offset := l_chars + 1;
        end loop;
 21   22   23      end print_clob_to_output;
begin
 24   25        dbms_output.enable(null);
 26     for item in c_ids
        loop
                if item.tot_rows >= 1000
 27   28   29           then
                        raise_application_error(-20001,'Maximum number of 1000 columns are not allowed',true);
                end if;
                out_string := item.id;
                if c_ids%rowcount = 1
                then
                        v_query := 'select';
 30   31   32   33   34   35   36                       dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
 37                     dbms_lob.append(v_query,' max(case when id = '''||out_string||''' then val end) as val_'||out_string||' , ');
                        dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
                        dbms_lob.append(v_query,' max(case when id = '''||out_string||''' then sum end) as sum_'||out_string||' ,');
 38   39   40           elsif c_ids%rowcount < item.tot_rows then
                        dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
                        dbms_lob.append(v_query,' max(case when id = '''||out_string||''' then val end) as val_'||out_string||' ,');
                        dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
                        dbms_lob.append(v_query,' max(case when id = '''||out_string||''' then sum end) as sum_'||out_string||' ,');
 41   42   43   44   45                 else
                        dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
 46   47                        dbms_lob.append(v_query,' max(case when id = '''||out_string||''' then val end) as val_'||out_string||' ,');
                        dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
                        dbms_lob.append(v_query,' max(case when id = '''||out_string||''' then sum end) as sum_'||out_string);
                end if;
 48   49   50   51      end loop;
        dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
        dbms_lob.append(v_query,'from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by val) as seqnum from t ) t');
        dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
        dbms_lob.append(v_query,'group by seqnum');
        print_clob_to_output(v_query);
 52   53   54   55   56   57  end;
/ 58
select
max(case when id = 'a' then val end) as val_a ,
max(case when id = 'a' then sum end) as sum_a ,
max(case when id = 'b' then val end) as val_b ,
max(case when id = 'b' then sum end) as sum_b ,
max(case when id = 'c' then val end) as val_c ,
max(case when id = 'c' then sum end) as sum_c ,
max(case when id = 'd' then val end) as val_d ,
max(case when id = 'd' then sum end) as sum_d ,
max(case when id = 'e' then val end) as val_e ,
max(case when id = 'e' then sum end) as sum_e ,
max(case when id = 'f' then val end) as val_f ,
max(case when id = 'f' then sum end) as sum_f ,
max(case when id = 'g' then val end) as val_g ,
max(case when id = 'g' then sum end) as sum_g ,
max(case when id = 'h' then val end) as val_h ,
max(case when id = 'h' then sum end) as sum_h
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by val) as seqnum from t ) t
group by seqnum

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select
  2  max(case when id = 'a' then val end) as val_a ,
max(case when id = 'a' then sum end) as sum_a ,
  3    4  max(case when id = 'b' then val end) as val_b ,
max(case when id = 'b' then sum end) as sum_b ,
max(case when id = 'c' then val end) as val_c ,
max(case when id = 'c' then sum end) as sum_c ,
  5    6    7    8  max(case when id = 'd' then val end) as val_d ,
max(case when id = 'd' then sum end) as sum_d ,
max(case when id = 'e' then val end) as val_e ,
  9   10   11  max(case when id = 'e' then sum end) as sum_e ,
 12  max(case when id = 'f' then val end) as val_f ,
max(case when id = 'f' then sum end) as sum_f ,
max(case when id = 'g' then val end) as val_g ,
max(case when id = 'g' then sum end) as sum_g ,
max(case when id = 'h' then val end) as val_h ,
max(case when id = 'h' then sum end) as sum_h
 13   14   15   16   17   18  from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by val) as seqnum from t ) t
group by seqnum 19  ;

     VAL_A      SUM_A      VAL_B      SUM_B      VAL_C      SUM_C      VAL_D      SUM_D      VAL_E      SUM_E      VAL_F      SUM_F      VAL_G      SUM_G      VAL_H       SUM_H
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3         15          4         22          5         90         10         33         22         50         10         10         12         12          10         10

SQL>

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Hope it helps, although I think the main query will only get you the max value for the IDs you have in the table. In case of two IDs are repeated, you will get the max value.

Regards